# Highlighting and Making notes in UIWebView - iPad

Tags: ios4

I want to make an app where I can select, highlight and make notes similar to iBook or Kindle in UIWebView and NOT UIView. For this I have to capture events (single or double click) and accordingly a menu will appear giving option of selecting the text and then either highlighting selected text or making notes at that point. My document is loaded in UIWebView.

Comment: Did You able to get the answer if yes then please help me or suggest me as i too need bookmarking, highlight and notes facility.